# jQuery / ajax, set select option

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking at setting the option for my select dropdown which has been passed back from the DB.

```
 "<td><select id=\"sel" + res.sku.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-') + "\"><option>True</option><option>False</option></select></td>" +
```

I have it passing over the option true or false, how would i go about setting this on the option please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to select one of the two automatically? Try `<option selected>`.

Comment: @thattuxguy Did you have a chance to try any of the answers that were posted?

Comment: Sorry, i chose to go down a different route. Basically it was silly to use a drop down as most items would be false as true is not displayed. So  i simply added a update button, which then updates the DB and removes the row from the table. 

Seemed to be the best way for this. I was only going to use a dropdown as the person who made the previous version of the software did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Sable that a radio button might be a better choice in this situation, but if you're determined to use a drop down list, you can try something like this:

```
"<option" + (myValue === true ? " selected" : "") + ">True</option><option" + (myValue === false? " selected" : "") + ">False</option></select></td>"
```

Comment: tested using this, and it worked well however i used a update button instead which made more sense. Thanks though, i will no doubt use this somewhere in the app :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the article: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

```
 $('#sel').prop('checked', false)
```

Or you could change the false to a true, depending upon your application's logic.

Comment: I'm not sure what checking a select element means. You'd at least need to specify the option.

Comment: You're right, @pimvdb.  I just reasoned that since it was a true or false, it would was a radio button, not a pull down (my mistake).  I might suggest that thatuxguy use a Radio button since true and false are mutually exclusive.